# Django application high disk IOPS on EC2

Tags: django, linux, amazon-ec2, celery

I am having sudden increases of high Disk IOPS on my EC2 instances. They are all running a Django 1.9.6 web application on it. The apps installed on it are Apache, Celery, New Relic Agent and Django Wsgi itself.
The application does not do any disk operations as such. Data is stored on RDS and Redis (Another server). The static files are stored on S3 and connected to cloudfront. So I am unable to determine what is the cause of this high Disk IOPS.

What happens is a normal request suddenly takes forever to respond. On checking cloudwatch and new relic I see the RAM usage shoots up. Then the instance is unresponsive. All requests time out and can't SSH in. When I contacted AWS Support they said the VolumeQueueLength was increasing significantly and once it came down (15-20 mins later) the instance was working fine.

Any ideas as to what could be the issue?

Comment: can you SSH in and run `iostat`? What OS are you using? I have noticed OS spikes in resources when `yum` autoupdate is running. Having a crappy disk IOPS and shared CPU only makes things worse.

Comment: As of now since the instance is fine, I am unable to get any data out of it. I have set atop to monitor from now on. It is running - Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.6.6. The instances are all t2.small but the thing is this issue has started recently. Previously there weren't any issues like this. Do note the application (django) hasn't been changed so a new version isn't the issue.

Comment: Given what you've said I still think it's one of the maintenance tasks that's causing this. Check your /etc/cron.daily monthly etc. Check for updates and apply then, then reboot the instances.